# Data normalization or smart search?

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, sphinx

My mysql table contains field say universities.

It can have following fields for example -

```
IIT

I.I.T.

Indian Institute Of Tech.

Indian Institute Of Technology

I-I-T
```

Now when user is searching for IIT, I want to search & show all these options not only IIT.

So what is the better way. Replacing last 4 options in database with IIT or in search somehow we understand IIT also matches with other options.

How popular site have implemented this code ??

Any help appreciated.

(I am using mysql, sphinxsearch, php .... but any logic provided is welcomed !!)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing "normalisation" one way or the other. You can either store the normalised data in the database upon input and simplify the search algorithm, or you essentially "normalise" the data during a search to find all possibilities, but you're going to do that every single time.

Which is better simply depends on whether you *want* to store the unnormalised data or not and whether normalisation during search is *too expensive* or not. Usually it's a better idea to have data stored as normalised as possible; but again, if that doesn't agree with your other goals for your data storage, then don't.